# MinGW path set but not being found at Powershell

Tags: c++, powershell, mingw

I just started learning C++ in class, and I have trouble setting up the built environment.
Our class uses MinGW and VS code for default building environment, so I followed the class guideline to install necessary MinGW libraries and added the directory of MinGW bin folder to environment variables(path).

So it worked well for the first time, but after reboot VS code cannot find gcc and g++. Typing gcc --version and g++ --version at cmd works well; it shows version info. However, typing that in Powershell(which VS code uses) does not work anymore.

I'm totally new to C++ and related environment, so I definitely have to fix this trouble. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a system environment variable, and the var name is "g++" with the value "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe"(replace this path with your g++.exe file path).Maybe you should restart your computer to apply this operation if the windows OS version is windows 10.